# @PostConstruct run when not all the properties of cascaded bean were initialized in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For example I got class A, B, C

```
@Service
public class A {

    private B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        b.computeUsingC();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    ...
}

@Service
public class B {

    private C c;

    public computeUsingC() {
        c.compute()
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    ...
}

@Service
public class C {
    private A a
    public void compute() {
        a.otherMethod();
    }
    ...
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

I got a NullpointException at line with: `c.compute()` when Spring starting up, because
c is not get wired yet.
I think `A` should not run method with annotation @PostConstruct before `B` is get fully initialized. Although B get instantiated only for itself.

Comment: Can you add more details? .. at first glance seems that should it work fine. @PostConstruct method starts when all is wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I got a cyclic reference for A -> B -> C -> A. So Spring cannot fully initialize B before using it.